# Brainf*ck to NASM converter written in C

Tags: c, assembly, brainfuck, compiler

I have made a very simple Brainfuck to NASM converter, that is usable for practically all programs. It has one trivial optimisation (to subsitute `ADD` for `INC` with large numbers). How can I make the generated code smaller and/or faster? I would prefer smaller over faster, if I had to choose.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static void usage(const char *);
static void compile_and_write(int);
static void print_header(void);
static void print_footer(void);

static FILE *in = NULL;
static FILE *out = NULL;

int
main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:h")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'i':
            in = fopen(optarg, "r");
            break;
        case 'o':
            out = fopen(optarg, "w");
            break;
        case 'h':
            usage(argv[0]);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        default:
            usage(argv[0]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (in == NULL) {
        in = stdin;
    }

    if (out == NULL) {
        out = stdout;
    }

    print_header();

    while ((ch = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
        compile_and_write(ch);
    }

    print_footer();

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void
print_header(
    void)
{
    fputs("[bits 64]\n", out);
    fputs("[section .bss]\n", out);
    fputs("mem:resb 32768\n", out);

    fputs("[section .text]\n", out);
    fputs("[global _start]\n", out);

    fputs("putc:\n", out);
    fputs("xor rax, rax\n", out);
    fputs("inc rax\n", out);
    fputs("xor rdi, rdi\n", out);
    fputs("inc rdi\n", out);
    fputs("xor rdx, rdx\n", out);
    fputs("inc rdx\n", out);
    fputs("syscall\n", out);
    fputs("ret\n", out);

    fputs("getc:\n", out);
    fputs("xor rax, rax\n", out);
    fputs("xor rdi, rdi\n", out);
    fputs("xor rdx, rdx\n", out);
    fputs("inc rdx\n", out);
    fputs("syscall\n", out);
    fputs("ret\n", out);

    fputs("_start:\n", out);
    fputs("mov rsi, mem\n", out);
}

static void
print_footer(
    void)
{
    fputs("mov rax, 60\n", out);
    fputs("xor rdi, rdi\n", out);
    fputs("syscall\n", out);
}

static void
compile_and_write(
    int ch)
{
    static int loop = 0;
    static int loops[0x10000] = {0};
    static size_t lp = 0;
    static unsigned cnt = 1;
    static int last = ' ';

    if (ch == last) {
        ++cnt;
        return;
    }

    switch (last) {
    case '+':
        if (cnt == 1) {
            fputs("inc byte [rsi]\n", out);
        } else {
            fprintf(out, "add byte [rsi], %u\n", cnt);
        }
        break;
    case '-':
        if (cnt == 1) {
            fputs("dec byte [rsi]\n", out);
        } else {
            fprintf(out, "sub byte [rsi], %u\n", cnt);
        }
        break;
    case '>':
        if (cnt == 1) {
            fputs("inc rsi\n", out);
        } else {
            fprintf(out, "add rsi, %u\n", cnt);
        }
        break;
    case '<':
        if (cnt == 1) {
            fputs("dec rsi\n", out);
        } else {
            fprintf(out, "sub rsi, %u\n", cnt);
        }
        break;
    case '.':
        while (cnt--) {
            fputs("call putc\n", out);
        }
        break;
    case ',':
        while (cnt--) {
            fputs("call getc\n", out);
        }
        break;
    case '[':
        while (cnt--) {
            loops[lp] = loop++;
            fprintf(out, "L%d:\n", loops[lp]);
            fprintf(out, "cmp byte [rsi], 0\n");
            fprintf(out, "jz E%d\n", loops[lp]);
            ++lp;
        }
        break;
    case ']':
        while (cnt--) {
            --lp;
            fprintf(out, "jmp L%d\n", loops[lp]);
            fprintf(out, "E%d:\n", loops[lp]);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    last = ch;
    cnt = 1;
}

static void
usage(
    const char *pname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-h] -i input -o output\n", pname);
}
```

Compilation command:

```
$ clang -Weverything -Werror -O2 -march=native -s -o bfc bfc.c
```

Usage (assume brainfuck input is `mandelbrot.b` and output is `mandelbrot`):

```
$ ./bfc -i mandelbrot.b -o mandelbrot.asm
$ nasm -Ox -w+all -w+error mandelbrot.asm
$ ld.gold -s -o mandelbrot mandelbrot.o
```

Note: this generates x86_64 assembly code for Linux (or compatible kernels) only. I might add i386 support later (perhaps in follow-up post).

Comment: There's a bug: if the file ends with an operation it won't be included.

Comment: You could try to detect code fragments of known structure, like multiplications or the like, and translate that to the appropriate short asm instructions/sequences.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow probably the extra newline, you can "fix" that by doing a `compile_and_write(0);` after the while loop;

Answer (score 4):

I'll skip any consideration about C code and comment only generated assembly code (as per your question).

1) In your generated code:

```
XOR AX, AX
INC RAX
XOR RDI, RDI
INC RDI
XOR RDX, RDX
INC RDX
```

You're stalling your pipeline, shuffle your instructions and you may also gain because of using available ALUs. More about this on [instruction scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_scheduling).

```
XOR RAX, RAX
XOR RDI, RDI
XOR RDX, RDX
INC RAX
INC RDX
INC RDI
```

2) On same code I see you have often this pattern:

```
XOR reg, reg
INC reg
```

If you replace it with:

```
MOV reg, 1
```

You will have same size but it may result on a small speed improvement (but it varies according to CPU).

3) You're extensively using `INC` and `DEC`, you may have a small performance gain using `ADD` and `SUB` (at least if you do not target an ancient CPU):

```
INC rsi
```

Also simplifying (and slightly speed-up) your C code it should be rewritten as:

```
ADD rsi, 1
```

4) Now you have:

```
CMP BYTE [rsi], 0
JZ ...
```

You're testing for zero using `CMP`. With a small change you will not gain in size but (again) in speed:

```
TEST BYTE [rsi], 0
JZ ...
```

`TEST` is faster than `CMP` but unfortunately they both can't be [macro-fused](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-operation#MACRO-FUSION) with `JZ` if second operand is an immediate value. Best would be to increase size in favor of speed (if you want so):

```
MOVZB AL, BYTE [rsi]
TEST AL, AL
JZ ...
```

4) If you do not really care about speed you can gain some extra bytes using `LOOP` instruction. For `.` and `,` commands you generate multiple `CALL` instructions. When `cnt >= 3` you may replace this:

```
CALL getc
CALL getc
CALL getc
```

With:

```
C0: MOV CX, 3
    CALL getc
    LOOPNZ C0
```

Note that `LOOP` instruction is (usually) pretty *bad* from performance point of view then you should do this only if you really want to optimize for size. Same *optimization* also may apply for `[` and `]` refactoring code little bit more.

5) In generated code you often have *patterns*, if you're optimizing for size then you may detect them to *compress* code replacing blocks with jumps (see this somehow as the opposite of inlining). For example `<+` is common pattern and it generates:

```
SUB rsi, 1
ADD BYTE [rsi], 1
```

If you detect this pattern then you will create a sub for it:

```
LTP1: SUB rsi, 1
      ADD BYTE [rsi], 1
      RET
```

And each time you find that code you simply:

```
CALL LPT1
```

This can be done both as *post-processing* on generated assembly or during you compilation phase. During compilation is easier (but you have to handle each pattern by hand) however it makes easy to also handle sequences like `<+++` simply passing an *argument* through register.

6) All these done you should consider to perform **multi-step optimization**:

- First generate an [intermediate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language) easier to analyze and optimize.
- Optimize this code using high-level knowledge (locally, across functions and whole program). You may add loops, pre-calculate invariants and so on. See also [Is inline assembly language slower than native C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9601427/1207195).
- Generate assembly code from intermediate code.
- Optimize generated assembly code (if assembler you're using isn't doing this for you). Sometimes this kind of optimizations are called *peephole* optimizations and they're highly local (for example one jump followed by a `MOV` may simply perform a conditional `MOV` and you may use faster and shorter `CMOV` instead).

Answer (score 2):

Adriano Repetti already did a wonderful job reviewing your generated assembly, so I'm mainly going to touch into the C a little bit.

---

> ```
> static void usage(const char *);
> ```

What is with all the `static` functions? This is the main C file and, as far as I can tell, the only C file in this project. These `static`s aren't needed.

---

You have *waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyyyyyyyyy* to many function calls:

> ```
> fputs("[bits 64]\n", out);
> fputs("[section .bss]\n", out);
> fputs("mem:resb 32768\n", out);
>
> fputs("[section .text]\n", out);
> fputs("[global _start]\n", out);
>
> fputs("putc:\n", out);
> fputs("xor rax, rax\n", out);
> fputs("inc rax\n", out);
> ...
> ```

You repeat something like this a lot in your code. And, each time you have a big chunk of these writes like this, you are always doing the same thing: writing something to `out`.

It would be a whole lot faster if you just used one function call for each chunk of these:

```
fputs("[bits 64]\n"
      "[section .bss]\n"
      "mem:resb 32768\n"
      ...
      ..., out);
```

---

Always prefer local variables over global ones in C; it is much better practice as it is less error-prone and more maintainable.

I'm not going to go into how you can refactor some of these global variables, but take a look at the ones you have and see if there is a way you can make them local.

For example, that compiling function declares a few at the start. Instead, you might be able to return that information as a struct like `compilation_data` (or something like that) and have it accept a compilation data struct as an argument. This could also allow for some interesting future features.

---

> ```
>     if (cnt == 1) {
>         fputs("inc byte [rsi]\n", out);
>     } else {
>         fprintf(out, "add byte [rsi], %u\n", cnt);
>     }
> ```

Save yourself the conditional: `add` is faster than `inc`, so why not just use `add`?

```
fprintf(out, 'add byte [rsi], %u\n", cnt);
```

---